# How to limit Box2D bodies to only be affected on 1 axis

Tags: box2d, flutter

I have a side scrolling game, where I am randomly placing trees, bushes etc.. I would like these bodies to fall ( To Align with the ground ) but not to slide.

What is the best way to achieve this and to avoid the bodies moving left to right.

Current Create Body Code:

```
final shape = new CircleShape();
shape.radius = 60;
shape.p.x = 0.0;

final activeFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
activeFixtureDef.shape = shape;
activeFixtureDef.restitution = 0.1;
activeFixtureDef.density = 5.00;
activeFixtureDef.friction = 0.1;

//Set mask bit filter for collision avoidance
Filter filter = Filter();
filter.groupIndex = -1;
activeFixtureDef.filter = filter;

FixtureDef fixtureDef = activeFixtureDef;
final activeBodyDef = new BodyDef();
activeBodyDef.linearVelocity = new Vector2(0.0, 0.0);
activeBodyDef.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
activeBodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
BodyDef bodyDef = activeBodyDef;
```

Comment: I know that you can do this in Bullet with `setLinearFactor` to 0. But I don't know if there is anything like that in Box2d.

Comment: Have you considered not making them bodies at all, but rather finding the correct height to place them using a raycast or other shapecast?

Comment: @DMGregory I considered it, but I use Perlin Noise to generate the ground so it would be very difficult to do this.

Comment: That makes it even easier. Now you don't even need any physics queries, you can just sample the height from your noise function. Want to try editing your question to instead ask "How can I place objects at the right height on my generated terrain?" and show us your generation code?